# Extend Log4j2 Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2, spring-boot-test

I have a wrapper for log4j2 Logger class - e.g.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
       
public class MyLogger extends Logger {
    protected MyLogger(LoggerContext context, String name, MessageFactory messageFactory) {
        super(context, name, messageFactory);
    }

    ....
    
}
```

I am trying to extend the [LoggerTest](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerTest.java) class to verify `MyLogger` functionality (so I can run the contained test and add new ones). I've tried something like the following:

```
@SpringBootTest
@LoggerContextSource(
    value = "log4j-test2.xml",
    reconfigure = ReconfigurationPolicy.AFTER_EACH
)
public class MyLoggerTest extends LoggerTest {
    public MyLoggerTest(LoggerContext context, ListAppender app, ListAppender host, ListAppender noThrown) {
        super(context, app, host, noThrown);
    }
}
```

`org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [org.apache.logging.log4j.test.appender.ListAppender arg1] in constructor....`

I tried creating a local implementation of `@LoggerContextSource` and the property resolver/extensions classes it references (`@Extensions({@ExtendWith({LoggerContextResolver.class}), @ExtendWith({ConfigurationResolver.class}), @ExtendWith({AppenderResolver.class})})`) and referencing those instead
e.g

```
@MyLoggerContextSource(
    value = "log4j-test2.xml",
    reconfigure = ReconfigurationPolicy.AFTER_EACH
)
```

```
...
@Extensions({
   @ExtendWith({MyLoggerContextResolver.class}), 
   @ExtendWith({MyConfigurationResolver.class}), 
   @ExtendWith({MyAppenderResolver.class})
})
public @interface MyLoggerContextSource {
...
}
```

but get `Duplicate ParameterResolver...` error for `LoggerContextResolver` and `MyLoggerContextResolver`

Is there anyway I can extend the log4j2 tests?

Comment: I am by no means a junit expert, but I notice that you omitted the @Named annotation on the parameters. While I didn't write the Log4j unit test tooling I would bet that without that the arguments to the constructor will be null.

Comment: @rgoers turns out it was the `@Named`. I was convinced that I had tried it before and it wasn't working, but maybe I was missing something else as well at the time (still newbie to java/spring...). Anycase it is working now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rgoers, turns out I was missing the `@Named` annotation on the parameters.

So my `MyLoggerTest` works with the following:

```
@SpringBootTest
@LoggerContextSource(
    value = "log4j-test2.xml",
    reconfigure = ReconfigurationPolicy.AFTER_EACH
)
public class MyLoggerTest extends LoggerTest {
    public MyLoggerTest(final LoggerContext context, @Named("List") final ListAppender app, @Named("HostTest") final ListAppender host, @Named("NoThrowable") final ListAppender noThrown) {
        super(context, app, host, noThrown);
    }
}
```